# Displacement over time graph sloping down has positive velocity

Tags: time, displacement

Why does this displacement over time graph sloping down have a positive velocity? Intuition would tell me that if it slopes up its positive velocity and if it slopes down its negative velocity. Am I missing something about these graphs or is Khan Academy wrong?

[**Graph**,](https://screenshots.firefox.com/eRl9GU0yF25tOOt4/www.khanacademy.org)
[**Answer**](https://screenshots.firefox.com/D09p5GVzrbyDZ0Dn/www.khanacademy.org)

Comment: Please give a link to a relevant Khan Academy video.

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/one-dimensional-motion/displacement-velocity-time/e/instantaneous-velocity-and-instantaneous-speed-exercise 

not a video but exercise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may be trying to catch you out by using the term "speed" instead of "velocity". Speed is a scalar quantity and represents the magnitude of the velocity, so it is always positive. The instantaneous *velocity* at 1 second is indeed -0.25 m/s, but the *speed* is 0.25 m/s

Comment: that was it, I was being blind. Will read instructions next time :)